# Allow App Instalation via QR code without opening Google Play

Tags: android, mobile, installation, apk, store

I've scoured the internet for the past 4 hours, but can't find any reliable information. I want to allow the user to download and install an APK via QR Code only - WITHOUT opening Google Play Store. Reasons behind it are 100% legit, as the devices will only be a showcase devices, without any additional features or any use by private or corporate entities.

I hoped to solve this problem by putting a download APK link, but some sources say it will not work that way. Thank you for all your help and I am sorry if my searches didn't turn a result that's already out there, I hope you'll forgive me lol

Best,
Luke

Comment: You can make a QR code out of a download link, in the format like "https://**.***.***/****.apk" and let others scan and download the app directly

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear that :)